# Shortcut for accessing lots of fields from same object (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, data-structures

Currently I have this line of code:

```
[@organisation.name, @organisation.address, @organisation.city, @organisation.postcode, @organisation.country, @organisation.phone_number].join(', ')
```

It seems unnecessarily verbose.

Is there a way to just state `@organisation` once, and get the various fields you want from it?

Answer (score 2):

I separated it out into separate lines for clarity, but it can be a one-liner.

```
fields = [:name, :address, :city, :postcode, :country, :phone_number]
values = fields.map { |field| @organisation.send(field) }
csv = values.join(', ')
```

The `send` method is the magic you were after. It 'sends' a method call to an object and returns the result of that method call.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ruby 2.3, you can try this:

```
@organisation.attributes.fetch_values("name", "address", "city", "postcode", "country", "phone_number").join(', ')
```

Comment: What about Ruby <2.3, is there anything e.g. for 2.2?

Comment: The method `fetch_values` is implemented in Ruby 2.3. 
For Ruby < 2.3,  I guess using others' solutions will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As evidenced by the answer that refers to "send", your question is not too clear, but under one interpretation, `instance_variables` would be the magic you're looking for.